# How to monitor the ports of AliCloud private ECS using local prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

I have setup a server in my company IDC room with prometheus installed on it, I have two AliCloud ECS servers, one has public and private IPs, this one has pushgateway installed on it, and the other server has only private IP. Now I want to use local prometheus to monitor some application ports on the ecs with only private IP, how should I do it?

The architecture is shown below:
[image]